# ggplot2: plotting time series data by month & week

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to plot time series data by week and month; ideally, I think, I'd like to use boxplots to visualise daily data binned by week. While I can change the labels and gridlines on the x-axis using [`scale_x_date`](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/scale_date.html), that won't affect the points in the plot.

Here's a demonstration of the problem and my current (clumsy) solution.

```
library(zoo)
library(ggplot2)

d = as.Date(c(as.Date("2007-06-01"):as.Date("2008-05-31"))) # using zoo to reformat numeric 
x = runif(366, min = 0, max = 100)
df = data.frame(d,x)

# PROBLEM #    
p = ggplot(df, aes(d, x))
p + geom_point()
p + geom_boxplot() # more or less useless

# CURRENT FIX #
df$Year.Month <- format(df$d, "%Y-%m")
p = ggplot(df, aes(Year.Month, x))
p + geom_point(alpha = 0.75)
p + geom_boxplot() # where I'm trying to get to...
```

I feel certain that there's a more elegant way to do this from within `ggplot`. Am I right?

@shadow's answer below is much neater. But is there a way to do this using binning? Using `stats` in some form, perhaps?

Comment: You can do the same thing you did seperately in `ggplot`: `p+geom_boxplot(aes(x=format(d, "%Y-%m")))`

Comment: Thanks @shadow - that is much neater.

Comment: Or perhaps this variation on shadow's code: `p + geom_boxplot(aes(format(as.yearmon(d))))`

Comment: That's interesting -- apparently the `as.yearmon` doesn't return the series in chronological order (I wonder why?) Also, it doesn't quite get me through the weekly issue -- although I might use `lubridate` to achieve the same thing, perhaps?

Answer (score 2):

You can treat Dates as dates in R, and use scale_x_date() in ggplot to get the x-labels you want.

- Also, I find it easier to just create a new variable-factor called "Month" to group the boxplots by month. In this case I used lubridate to accomplish the task.
- If you do not want to go through the trouble of creating a new variable "Month", your bloxplot will be plotted on the 15th of the month, making the viz reading a bit more difficult.

  ```
  library(magrittr)
  library(lubridate)
  library(dplyr)

  df %>%
    mutate(Date2 = as.Date(paste0("2000-", month(d), "-", "01"))) %>%
    mutate(Month = lubridate::month(d)) %>%

  ggplot(aes(Date2, x, group=Month)) +
    geom_boxplot() +
    scale_x_date(date_breaks="1 month", date_labels = "%b")
  ```

[image]

If you do not create the variable "Month", boxplots won't align nicely with the x tick marks:

[image]

Comment: I like the way that these line up; however you appear to have lost the year data. There are 13 month labels in the lower chart (but they do run June to June inclusive). In the top chart, there are 12 months, but they run from Jan to Dec.)

Comment: @mediaczar, I see 12 months on the lower chart. From may-07 to jun-08, just like the data. When the factor month is created, the default is to plot from jan-to-dec, but if we re-rank the months, it could go from jun-to-may. Think of this exercise with several years instead of only 12 months of data...

Comment: yes. The x-axis on the lower chart makes sense. It's the top chart with which I'm taking issue. You'll note too, simply by eyeballing the boxplots, that the data are in a different order.

To be fair, I've not used the `lubridate` library before and haven't had a chance to check out how to fix what is - no doubt - a simple issue in a great solution.

Comment: Note that the *order* for the boxplots is the same, although one series starts at Jun, and the other one in Jan. The "Jun boxplot" is the same for the top and bottom charts. Let's what else solution we get here.